# A copy of XXX has been removed from the module but is still active

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am basically running a background process that checks for files, and then updates the rails model based on the data discovered in the file. However, I can't access the model from within the thread because of an error.

Here's my example:

```
def check_logs
    while @start == 1
        results = Dir.glob("#{@path}/*.txt")
        unless results.empty?
            results.each do |result|
                file_name = result.split("/")[-1]
                data = File.open(result).read

                if file_name.include? "get"
                    data_contents = data.split("\n")
                    time = data_contents[0]
                    ExamResult.create(time: time)
                end
                FileUtils.rm_rf result
            end
        end

        sleep 5
    end
end

def start_agent
    @start = 1
    Thread.start {check_logs}
end

def stop_agent
   @start = 0
end
```

However, while it's in the background, this is the error that I see coming across the console:

> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
>   Traceback (most recent call last):    5: from
>   portal/lib/custom_rb/exam_results/exam_custom.rb:69:in `block in
>   start_monitoring_agent'   4: from
>   portal/lib/custom_rb/exam_results/exam_custom.rb:40:in`check_logs'
>     3: from portal/lib/custom_rb/exam_results/exam_custom.rb:40:in `each'
>     2: from portal/lib/custom_rb/exam_results/exam_custom.rb:46:in`block
>   in check_logs'    1: from
>   /home/nutella/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in `const_missing'
>   /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:496:in`load_missing_constant': A copy of ExamResult has been removed from
>   the module tree but is still active! (ArgumentError)

My goal here is just to have a backgrounded process to monitor for logs. I've seen some other posts about this same exact error, but perhaps I could be doing this a little better other than the solutions provided for them.

Any thoughts or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that provided error is somehow related to the code above.
Usually, this error happens when you modify your classes at runtime with metaprogramming.

Take a look at places where you require, define `ExamResult`, it looks like you require it several times in your code.

Comment: Yeah that's the only function that ExamResult is mentioned. If I remove the Thread.start {check_logs}, I never get the error. It seems that it works just fine at first, but if I refresh the web page, it's almost like my ability to call that model goes away.

Comment: That happens because Rails reloads your models on the page refresh, and that constant, that previously pointed to the ExamResult, is not available anymore. I'd not recommend you to write threaded code in the scope of Rails app. Take a look at Sidekiq gem, for example. It'll do that in safe way for you.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried sidekiq, but it doesn't look like you can actually stop a sidekiq worker right? For example, this code checks an instance variable to see if it changed and it stops if so. However, I don't think I can do the same in sidekiq no?

Comment: Well, you can implement almost the same logic inside of sidekiq worker. If some conditions are met, then you can just return from sidekiq job's `perform` method, and it will stop, until the next job is scheduled.
As an alternative, you can give a try to https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons gem, that is built for writing long-running applications and servers.

Comment: Gotcha. Perhaps the sidekiq worker can check the database for an updated status every 5 seconds. Not sure if that'd be a heavy hit to performance, but I'll give it a shot. I really appreciate it!

Comment: So I just converted this into a sidekiq worker, but the sidekiq worker is having another problem. It seems to be accessing an old instance of the model. Is there a way to allow it to get the current model data?

Comment: Sure. 'my_object.reload' should pull changed attributes from the database.